# Conditions for linear independence given the family of vectors is pairwise independent

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, independence, linear-independence

let $n>0, n \in \mathbb{N}$
Given $n+1$ vectors $a_0, a_1, ... a_n$ which are pairwise independent i.e. for all $i,j \in \{ 0,1,...,n \}$ and  $i\neq j$, $a_i$ and $a_j$ are linearly independent.
Under what conditions is $a_0, a_1, ... a_n$ a linearly independent family?
This is of course not true in general. For eg: we can find infinitely many pairwise independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ but not more than 2 can form a linearly independent family.

Comment: What kind of condition do you hope to get?

Comment: In $\mathbb R^3$, one can take $e_1,e_2,e_1+e_2$. This then suggests that one needs some sort of orthogonality condition.

Comment: Anything sufficient, but it should obviously make use of the given conditions.

Comment: Pairwise linearly independent just means that they aren't scalar multiples of each other. That is essentially unhelpful. Consider $\{e^{\pi a} \in \mathbb{C} \ : \ a\in [0, 1)\}$ those are all pairwise linearly independent.

Comment: Yes of course I do understand that. Even in $R^2$ we can take as many vectors as we want in the unit circle and they would follow this condition. Does this not help in any way though?

Comment: No, it really doesn't. This condition is so weak, if you insult it, it dies of emotional damage. It's a bit like saying if none of the vectors is nonzero (i.e. linearly independent with itself) what do we need to make collection linearly independent in its entierty. The answer is "a lot". Of course I can give you conditions that tell you that your family is linearly independent, but none of them will use your condition in a meaningful way. It's like asking how your toddler can help you solving the Riemann hypothesis. Not hurting themself would be great, but that won't help you much...